Is this condition enough to assume the functions are inverses?
Given $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow X$ with $X\cap Y=\emptyset$.
If $f\circ g(x)=x$ is true, is $g\circ f(x)=x$ also true?
Can somebody provide a counter example? The normal one I found is with $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, but this does not statisfy the disjoint set condition above.

Let   $Y=\{1\}$, $X=\{2,3\}$, $g(1)=2$, $f(2)=f(3)=1$, then
the condition $f(g(x))=x$ is satisfied, but $g(f(3))=2$.

$$ f : [-3,-2]\cup [2,3] \to [4,9],\quad  f(x)=x^2 \\ g : [4,9] \to [-3,-2]\cup [2,3] ,\quad  g(x)=\sqrt{x}$$
